# Why I can't connect my Python script to my SQL file?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Hello I try to add data to my SQL database with my Python script and it does not recognize my file SQL, maybe I need to add the database and name server but I don't know how to do it
My script in Python:

`import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
connection_db=sqlite3.connect("MyDB.sql")
action_db=connection_db.cursor()
action_db.execute("""create table Peoples (ID int identity(1,1) primary key,"First Name" varchar(50) not null,"Last Name" varchar(50) not null,Age int not null,
City varchar(50) not null,"Register date" datetime not null)""") #This is for create the table in SQL file
action_db.execute('insert into Peoples values ('Paz','Leviim',20,'Rishon',\'{}\')'.format(datetime.now()))
connection_db.close()`

And all of this not working maybe I  need somewhere to add the name server and database that I've created before but I don't know how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do more homework on how to use sqlite3 in python.

Review [sqlite3 API doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) as it relates to database path:

> sqlite3.**connect**(database[, timeout, detect_types, isolation_level,
>   check_same_thread, factory, cached_statements, uri])
>
> Opens a connection to the SQLite database file database. By default returns a Connection object, unless a custom factory is given.
>
> *database* is a path-like object giving the pathname (absolute or relative to the current working directory) of the database file to be
>   opened. You can use ":memory:" to open a database connection to a
>   database that resides in RAM instead of on disk.

For this code, `MyDB.sql` must live in the same path where the python script is executing. (If no such file exists, one will be created).

Mismatched quotes here:

`action_db.execute('insert into Peoples values ('Paz','Leviim',20,'Rishon',\'{}\')'.format(datetime.now()))`

Other problems:

- create table will fail if table exists
- not enough arguments to insert
- no commit